# Teensy MIDI Show Control

Tags: teensy, midi

I'd like to use my Teensy 3.1 to send MIDI Show Control messages using USB MIDI in order to control an ETC Nomad system. These are different from standard NoteOn, NoteOff, ProgramChange, etc. commands, but as far as I can tell they are not supported by the standard library.

Is there any way I can send these messages directly (using lower level commands), as seen [here](http://www.mymidiremotes.com/home/?page_id=46), or does anyone know of a library that supports this? Google has, unusually, not been much help.

Comment: Where does USB come into this? The example you linked to shows exactly how to send non-standard MIDI messages.

Comment: @JakeC I just linked to that page to differentiate between MSC messages and standard MIDI note messages. I'm not using hardware MIDI, but using the Teensy as a USB MIDI device.

Comment: In which case this is more a matter of finding computer software to send those messages if you are just having the Teensy act as a bridge.

Comment: Also, Teensy is a rather expensive way of doing this at ~$20 compared to a ~5 USB MIDI cable.

Comment: ~$5 MIDI cable, a $10+ MIDI interface for my MacBook, and an extra PCB to house the ports and other components, vs a Teensy I already had on my desk

Comment: I totally understand the need it now, however, there is still nothing special you would have to do in the Teensy to make it work with MSC if you are just setting it up to relay what it gets from the computer. Any work you need to do is in what software you are using on your computer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/td_midi.html), SysEx messages are sent like any other messages:

```c
array[0] = 0xf0;
array[1] = 0x7f;
array[2] = 0x7f;
array[3] = 0x02;
array[4] = 0x7f;
array[5] = 0x01;
array[6] = 0xf7;
usbMIDI.sendSysEx(7, array);
```